# How can I use an iterator from a "For Each" as a String parameter to a function when all iterators are declared as "Variant"?

Tags: vba, function, types, parameters

So I'm trying to use the iterator *OutDirectoryPath* from a "For Each" block as a parameter to this function:

```
Function GetFilePathArrayFromDirectory(directoryPath As String) As String()
    'some code here
End Function
```

Here is how I pass it:

```
Dim OutDirectoryPath
For Each OutDirectoryPath In OutFolderPaths
        
        Dim FilePathArray() As String
        
        FilePathArray = GetFilePathArrayFromDirectory(OutDirectoryPath)
    
Next OutDirectoryPath
```

The problem is that I get a Compile Error because every iterator from a "For Each" block is declared automatically as a "Variant", and it is assigned as a String only at runtime. My question is how can I use iterators as parameters if they will always have the "Variant" type, without changing the function's arguments to "Variant"?

Comment: `Dim OutDirectoryPath As String`?

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII A `String` [cannot be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement#syntax) an iteration variable in a `For Each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a variant to a string by using `CStr`:

`FilePathArray = GetFilePathArrayFromDirectory(CStr(OutDirectoryPath))`